# What if a GET request with _primary_shard preference land on a node which only have replica shards?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch2

I was getting duplicate records in ES 2.2.1. So, I started using preference _primary_first for GET requests.
But, I notice that there is no request landing on my 4th node in a cluster of 4 nodes. This node consist of two replicas.

Is it the case that node with replica will never cater to the requests coming with _primary_first preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-preference.html)

`The operation will be executed on primary shards if possible, but will fall back to other shards if not`

This is the behavior of `_primary_first`. Reason for no requests on replica-only-node is that all of your requests are resolved by primary modes and no need was there to be executed on replica-only node.

And you are using very older version.

Regarding your duplicate documents:

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615227/elasticsearch-allows-duplicate-id-with-different-body-data), [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082379/duplicate-documents-in-elasticsearch-index-with-the-same-uid)

You should mainly look at `routing` to identify the cause for the duplicates.

Comment: I have not checked routing, will check it now.